# wordpress simple shortcodes not rendered when using Timber plugin

Tags: wordpress, twig, timber

I've recently taken over dev of a Wordpress site using Timber (which I wasn't familiar with).  I'm attempting to use a new plugin and accompanying shortcode, which of course doesn't work.

I've been researching this for a couple hours and there doesn't seem to be a simple answer.  In order to use a simple shortcode like this:

[sp_faq category="7"]

Do I really need to create a custom shortcode function in functions.php, add some sort of template file for it, etc?  This seems counterintuitive to Twig's making things 'simple'.

The documentation for this is less than stellar unless I'm missing something obvious.

Answer (score 3):

You could try this (example using a gravity form shortcode):

```
{% filter shortcodes %}
  [gravityforms id="1"]
{% endfilter %}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to render a shortcode from a custom field you can do it like this:

```
{{post.custom_shortcode_field|shortcodes}}
```

Taken from the docs:
https://timber.github.io/docs/guides/filters/#shortcodes

Or if it's comming from the main-editor try:

```
{{ post.content|wpautop }}
```

Comment: Yeah I've read the documentation, but I can't drop this in the regular content area can I?  It doesn't do anything there.

Comment: You would use this lines in your Twig template files. To do a quicktest regarding shortcodes: you should have at least {{ post.content }} in the matching template. Try adding the |wpautop filter if it's not allready there.

Comment: In my template file it had {{ page.post_content }} which my understanding outputs values exactly as stored in the db.

I tried changing this to {{ post.content|wpautop }} but nothing is rendered on the page, including any plain text.

Comment: {{ post.content|wpautop }}  doesn't work but {{ page.content|wpautop }}   does, although it still outputs raw content, nothing rendered.

Comment: What happens if you write {{ page.content|shortcodes }} ?

Comment: @KevinJohnson: if the prior twig file had `{{ page.post_content }}`, then `{{ page.content }}` will do the trick. 

If it still doesn't work, confirm that the `sp_faq` shortcode functions in a non-Timber/Twig template. I've sometimes found the cause is elsewhere in the chain

Comment: {{ page.content|wpautop }} and 
{{ page.content }}
both returns unparsed shortcodes.   Unfortunately I don't have time to investigate this further (due to budget), actually looking like it will be easier to just slap on a new non-Timber Wordpress theme.

Answer (score 2):

Reads like you want to use a shortcode outside of post.content.

You can use `{% function('do_shortcode', '[shortcode here]') %}` to process a shortcode where ever you want to in a template.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like this is too late for OP, but for anyone else coming across this: The correct solution is combined in the Luckyfella's answer and the comments on it. I think OP would have got it working if he had tried Luckyfella's final suggestion.

You need to put `{{post.post_content|wpautop|shortcodes}}`* into your Twig file(s). This will render both auto paragraphs and shortcodes that are put into the main WYSIWYG editor, by default.

*`post` is simply the conventional default name in Timber for a `TimberPost`, you will also need to check in your PHP template files to see what the Timber context and Timber post variables are called. For OP it seems to have been `page`, not post.

Comment: I actually did eventually figure it out, I should have come back and posted the solution.  It was as simple as 
{{ page.content|wpautop|shortcodes }}

I didn't really understand Twig templates when I first started working on it, and I don't think anyone realized how simple of a solution I needed, lol.

Comment: @rickibarnes I have an issue that is similar to what you mentioned in your solution. I am using timber and twig templates and my posts are displayed using single.twig file. I have `[gallery link="file" size="medium" ids="594,593,592] ` shortcode in the post content blog on wysiwyg editor. But the solution that you mentioned is not working for me.

Answer (score 1):

Just thought I'd chime in here.

`post.post_content` contains the *raw* data that is contained in the database (before any filters have been applied to it) and `post.content` contains the data *after* the filters have been applied, so using the filter `|shortcodes` shouldn't be needed to be run on that.

I was using `post.post_content` for some reason and found this question because I was trying to figure out why my shortcodes weren't working and hence it led me to do some more research.

Now, reading the answers in this question, I wasn't really satisfied with as I had also been using `|e('wp_kses_post')` to sanatise the data that I output, but if I used something like this:

```
{{ post.content|wpautop|e('wp_kses_post') }}
```

...then obviously I would get the correct filtered data with the shortcodes processed, but it would also at the same time strip out any non-allowed data with the `e('wp_kses_post')` filter.

Sure, you could add *allowable* tags within this filter, but obviously that isn't very realistic as you don't know exactly what output the shortcodes will be outputting nor do you want to keep updating it.

So, we had a problem... we want to *allow* shortcodes to be parsed, but also sanatise the content at the same time - what to do!?

**The solution is the below:**

```
{{ post.post_content|wpautop|e('wp_kses_post')|apply_filters('the_content') }}
```

Here we use `post.post_content` so we have the content *before* it has been filtered, *then* after the `wpautop` filter it is followed by `e('wp_kses_post')`; this will sanatise the data, but the important part being it will leave shortcodes alone, so they can be *still* be filtered!

Lastly, we apply the filters for the content with the `apply_filters` filter, and this then takes care of all the filters applied to `the_content` including parsing the shortcodes.

Though if you are already using [universal escaping](https://timber.github.io/docs/guides/escapers/) you will have to consider how the above will apply to your situation.