# Trying to load a WP Plugin Shortcode from a .twig file

Tags: wordpress, twig, shortcode, timber

I tried asking this question on [a related thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47440122/wordpress-simple-shortcodes-not-rendered-when-using-timber-plugin/66432837#66432837), but it was deleted without any notification (I understand I wasn't offering a solution, but a heads up that you were deleting my post would've been helpful...I'm new here). I'm retrying here:

I have never used Timber before and have the Easy Accordion Pro plugin with a generated shortcode of "[sp_easyaccordion id="352"]" and have tried the following in my .twig template file (which lives in Themes>My Theme>templates) and all that renders is plain text [sp_easyaccordion id="352"]. Any thoughts?

```
{% function('do_shortcode', '[sp_easyaccordion id="352"]') %}
```

OR

```
{{ function('do_shortcode', '[sp_easyaccordion id="352"]') }}
```

OR

```
{% filter shortcodes %}
{{ wp.do_shortcode('[sp_easyaccordion id="352"]') }}
{% endfilter %}
```

OR

```
{{ wp.do_shortcode('[sp_easyaccordion id="352"]') }}
```

AND simply

`{% filter shortcodes %} [sp_easyaccordion id="352"] {% endfilter %}`

None of these worked. Please also note that I did not add anything to my function.php file...is that something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://timber.github.io/docs/guides/wp-integration/#layouts-with-shortcodes) it should be:

```
{% filter shortcodes %}
    [sp_easyaccordion id="352"]
{% endfilter %}
```

Otherwise you should also be able to call a function as such:

```
{{ function('do_shortcode', '[sp_easyaccordion id="352"]') }}
```

https://timber.github.io/docs/guides/functions/#function

Comment: I have tested on a clean installation of WordPress with Timber and EasyAccordion and both the methods work. I can only suggested enabling WP_DEBUG and WP_DEBUG_LOG to check for errors as something else is likely causing the issue in your twig file.